# WPF Bind List of string values in an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have the following Model class

```
 ResultViewModel
 public string word {get;set;}
 public List<string> meanings {get;set;}
```

With 2 properties  . How can i bind the List of meanings string to a stack panel ?

My datas will be like

word="a" , meanings= "a1","a2","a3"

word="b" , meanings= "b1","b2","b3"....

word="c" , meanings= "c1","c2","c3"....

I have following xaml which will help me to bind "a" "b"  "c" etc But now i want to show the meaning to its bottom

```
    <ItemsControl Name="lviewLookupResult"  Background="#363636">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>                  
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5 5 5 0">                          
                        <Label Margin="5 0" Padding="0"  Content="{Binding word}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5 5 5 0">                            

                        ??????HOW CAN I SHOW Meanings HERE???????????


                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I am using below code to bind the model and binding is fine on run time

```
  List<ResultViewModel> view_model = new List<ResultViewModel>();           
   lviewLookupResult.ItemsSource = view_model;
```

Comment: You can use an `ItemsControl` too.

Answer (score 4):

Use another `ItemsControl` like this:

```
   <ItemsControl Name="lviewLookupResult"  Background="#363636">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5 5 5 0">
                        <Label Margin="5 0" Padding="0"  Content="{Binding word}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ItemsControl Margin="5 5 5 0" ItemsSource="{Binding meanings}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this updated XAML.

```
<ItemsControl Name="lviewLookupResult"  Background="#363636">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5 5 5 0">
                    <Label Margin="5 0" Padding="0"  Content="{Binding word}" />
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding meanings}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

What i suggest is to create a class called `MeaningsCollection` and override the `ToString` method.

```
public class MeaningsCollection
{
    public List<string> meanings {get;set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "the collection in your preferred format";
    }
}

public class ResultViewModel 
{
     public string word {get;set;}
     public MeaningsCollection Meanings {get;set;}
}
```

And in your XAML should be something like:

```
<ItemsControl Name="lviewLookupResult"  Background="#363636">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>                  
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5 5 5 0">                          
                        <Label Margin="5 0" Padding="0"  Content="{Binding word}" />
                        <Label Margin="5 0" Padding="0"  Content="{Binding Meanings}" />
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I have to do few more actions with individual strings. So this solution wont work for me

Comment: You can add another property `MeaningsCollection` that return the List of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ItemsControl and set the ItemsPanel property.

```
<ItemsControl Name="lviewLookupResult"  Background="#363636">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                  
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5 5 5 0">                          
                    <Label Margin="5 0" Padding="0"  Content="{Binding word}" />
                </StackPanel>

                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding meanings}">                            
                      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5 5 5 0" />
                          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```